# Appending to link URL in an IFRAME

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, append

I have a page with an IFRAME. The IFRAME consists of newsfeed links to RSS articles. I would like to append to each article URL target="_blank", so that each article opens in a new window, not the IFRAME. I don't want to change the layout or function of the original newsfeed page, so I'm looking to dynamically append to the URL when clicked on. The main page and the IFRAME page are in the same domain. Any help would be appreciated.

Sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://vangopainting.net/painting-tips?tmpl=component"></iframe>
</body>
<html>
```

As you can see, the above URL pulls a stripped Joomla page, with just the content shown. This IFRAME will be embedded in a Facebook page, and when a user clicks on a link, it embeds the whole site in the IFRAME, not just the article. I would like for this to open in a new window, not the IFRAME, by appending target="_blank" to the URL, or even appending ?tmpl=component to the URL so that Joomla strips everything but the article.

Edited to add:
OK...here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('iframe').load(function(){
            $('a',$(this).contents()).each(function(){this.href = this.href + "?tmpl=component";});
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="link.html" width="100%" height="50px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://vangopainting.net/painting-tips?tmpl=component" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I added the first iframe just for testing purposes in Facebook.

The contents in link.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://vangopainting.net/painting-tips/508-newest-mobile-app-matches-paint-color-instantly">http://vangopainting.net/painting-tips/508-newest-mobile-app-matches-paint-color-instantly</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a direct link to the page: http://vangopainting.net/fb/tabs/paintingtips/index.html
Everything works as it should.

And here is a link to the Facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Van-Go-Painting-Inc/177992368936448?sk=app_366401100043274
The first iframe's URL is appended as it should, but the second iframe is untouched.

I'm at a losss as to why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
$('a',$('iframe').contents()).attr('target','_blank');
```

In short, it grabs the contents of all `iframe`s, finds their `a` tags, and applies the appropriate `target` attribute.

Add the following (untested) code snippet inside of the `head` tag in your example to achieve the desired effect.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('iframe').load(function(){
            $('a',$(this).contents()).attr('target','_blank');
        });
    });
</script>
```

There is a lot of waiting on events happening in the above snippet.

- First, we wait for the page to load by [passing a callback function to `$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3).  We want to wait for the page to load so we know we can find our `iframe`s.
- When that callback is performed, we find all `iframe`s and attach a different callback to be invoked when they are loaded.
- This different callback is the code snippet that does the actual work of finding the `a` tags and amending them.

Comment: @yahelc According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2), that restriction only applies to retrieving values with `attr()`; when setting values, it works for all matched elements.

Comment: Can you give me an example based on my sample code? Still learning and need to see a visual application. Where exactly should the code go, in the main page?

Comment: @CurtisHolzschuh I've amended my answer.  But I didn't test it, so ... good luck! :)

Comment: Works great as a stand-alone page: http://vangopainting.net/fb/tabs/paintingtips/index.html but embedded in Facebook it doesn't work: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Van-Go-Painting-Inc/177992368936448?sk=app_366401100043274

Comment: So, how would I append ?tmpl=component to the URL?

Comment: Change the relevant line to `$('a',$(this).contents()).each(function(){this.href = this.href + "?tmpl=component";});`.

Comment: Great! That worked. Thanks! Unfortunately, It doesn't work in Facebook. They must be stripping any additional attributes off URLs.

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work in Facebook"?  If you are talking about an `iframe` directing to Facebook, you will be unable to make any modifications to that `iframe` due to cross-domain restrictions.

Comment: I edited my question above to show my code so far and links to the page. Thanks cheeken for the help! I don't understand why on Facebook one URL in the top IFRAME is getting appended, but the other IFRAME is untouched. It works directly though, just not in the Facebook app.

Comment: This is getting really cluttered.  You might want to post another question.

Comment: OK...I got it figured out. The problem was that now that Facebook requires a secure server for apps, the index page (which is served  via HTTPS) is linked by a shared certificate on the server. But the IFRAME was linked directly, so to the browser, I was trying to cross-domain script. I had to turn Joomla SEF off to access the IFRAME page via HTTPS. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also had to turn mod-rewrite off in Joomla

Answer (score 0):

you can access the contents of the iframe using `.contents` and then find the elements inside the iframe using `.find` then using `each` modify the element to your liking, since you have not provided any code so im also going to stick to the theoretical answer